# Acessar base SQL Server via CMD

Tags: sql, sql-server

No Oracle sei que tem como acessar e executar queries através de sqlplus no CMD.

Alguém sabe dizer se pra SQL SERVER também tem algum comando semelhante?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> É possível gerenciar seus bancos de dados do Microsoft SQL Server 2008
>   Express (SQL Server Express) usando o utilitário sqlcmd no prompt de
>   comando. Para acessar o utilitário sqlcmd, clique em Iniciar, em
>   Executar e digite sqlcmd.exe.

Se não funcionar verifique se o caminho da pasta do sqlcmd.exe está adicionado na sua variável de ambiente PATH

REF:https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms165702(v=sql.105).aspx